# Excel Dependent Dropdown Menu

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu

I have 2 drop-down menus, A containing the values A1, A2, A3, and B with values B1, B2, B3.
I want to create a third menu with two drop-down options which are the values in the first two menus.

So, if we select A1 and B3, the third menu would have options: A1, B3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the third dropdown, use the data validation list option and as the source select the range from A2:B2

[image]

If the cells are not arranged in a contiguous way, create a helper table that references the desired cells and use it in the data validation.

[image]